Java module doesn't find package
I use Retrofit 2 for an API that I made, and I use Retrofit Gson to convert the API response to an object. I have a package with my JSON models (as a class) and I need Gson to access to those models.
When I add the line to open the package for Gson, I get an error on the building saying that they can't access to the package. I tried to open for the package above (that I know work because javafx.fxml uses it), but then I get this error (not on the building, but when I use Gson while running)
Exception in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.api.models.bankapi.response.get.LoginResponse
    for method BankApi.login
    at retrofit2@2.11.0/retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:56)
    at retrofit2@2.11.0/retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createResponseConverter(HttpServiceMethod.java:139)
    at retrofit2@2.11.0/retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:97)
    at retrofit2@2.11.0/retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:39)
    at retrofit2@2.11.0/retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:235)
    at retrofit2@2.11.0/retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:177)
    at jdk.proxy2/com.sun.proxy.jdk.proxy2.$Proxy6.login(Unknown Source)
    at fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop@1.0-SNAPSHOT/fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.SignInController$signIn$1.invokeSuspend(SignInController.kt:95)
    at kotlin.stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.core/kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.core/kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:589)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.core/kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:806)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.core/kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:710)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.core/kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@5216989, Dispatchers.Default]
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.api.models.bankapi.response.get.LoginResponse#message' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:38)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:286)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:130)
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.api.models.bankapi.response.get.LoginResponse#message' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.

    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:556)
    at retrofit2.converter.gson@2.11.0/retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(GsonConverterFactory.java:64)
    at retrofit2@2.11.0/retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:418)
    at retrofit2@2.11.0/retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:401)
    at retrofit2@2.11.0/retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createResponseConverter(HttpServiceMethod.java:137)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.String fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.api.models.bankapi.response.get.LoginResponse.message accessible: module fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop does not "opens fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.api.models.bankapi.response.get" to module com.google.gson
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.String fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.api.models.bankapi.response.get.LoginResponse.message accessible: module fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop does not "opens fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.api.models.bankapi.response.get" to module com.google.gson

    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at com.google.gson@2.10.1/com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.makeAccessible(ReflectionHelper.java:35)
    ... 19 more

here is my module-info.java
module fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires kotlin.stdlib;
    requires TranslationLibrary.main;
    requires kotlinx.coroutines.core;
    requires org.jetbrains.annotations;
    requires retrofit2;
    requires retrofit2.converter.gson;
    requires com.google.gson;

    opens fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop to javafx.fxml, retrofit2.converter.gson;
    exports fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop;
}

I push the project on GitHub, here is the link

The error message states "... module fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop does not "opens fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.api.models.bankapi.response.get" to module com.google.gson" (emphasis added)

"I try to add a line to give access ...": posted code does not contain that line, not the (source) package fr.plaglefleau. ... .reponse.get, neither the (destination) module com google.gson

There is no such thing as an “upper package”. Packages may form a hierarchy from our human’s perspective, but to Java, every package is distinct. You must open fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.api.models.bankapi.response.get exactly. And you must open it to com.google.gson, exactly. com.google.gson is not retrofit2.converter.gson. If you get an error about the package not being found, make sure that the classes of that package are included in this compiler run. As the exception message says, you can alternatively “write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type”.

I modified it to remove the retrofit2 and add a new line as indicated, but when I try to compile I got this error Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Package fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.api.models.bankapi.response.get not found in module
don't know how to fix it and also don't know how to create a custom TypeAdapter (I will try to find out how to create a custom TypeAdapter)

Regarding the Package ... not found in module error you are seeing after updating module-info.java:
The problem is most likely that your project consists of Java and Kotlin code, and the package you want to open is part of the Kotlin code.
You can probably solve this by either:

Adjusting your build.gradle so that the compileJava task can see the Kotlin classes, see the Kotlin documentation
Opening your complete module to all other modules for reflection, instead of individual packages. See also the related question: Can a module-info.java 'opens' statement include a package and all sub-packages? 
That is, change your module-info.java and remove opens ... to ...; and instead write open module:
open module fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop {
    requires ...
}

See also Understanding Java 9 Modules. This could however make troubleshooting more difficult when Gson or another library by accident uses reflection on a class from one of your packages which you did not actually want to open.

Note that Gson is mainly designed for Java.  It might work for some Kotlin features, but not for all (e.g. nullability is not considered). Since your model classes are written in Kotlin, it might be better to use a JSON library with explicit Kotlin support, for example https://github.com/square/moshi and corresponding Retrofit converter.

I open my module, and now it worked, thank you. I try to do the Gradle thing, but it only works on Gradle version less than 7, and I use Gradle 8.2 so didn't work for me

@PlagLeFleau, it should work with recent Gradle versions as well. The comment "Gradle version less than 7.0" in the code snippet of the Kotlin documentation refers to whether you need to set inferModulePath. On newer Gradle versions that is not necessary anymore.

Just to be sure: Try using gson 2.10.1 instead of 2.11.0
There was a change in 2.11.0 and as a result the JAR file of Gson does have the module-info.java in a subdirectory version/9 instead of the JAR's root.
The IDE Eclipse for example does not recognize this and maybe this explains your "Package not found" problem as well.

The solution is already provided in the root exception (emphasis mine):

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to
make field private final java.lang.String
fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.api.models.bankapi.response.get.LoginResponse.message
accessible: module fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop does not "opens
fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.api.models.bankapi.response.get" to
module com.google.gson

In other words, you need to modify your module-info.java and add the following opens statement.
opens fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.api.models.bankapi.response.get 
        to com.google.gson;


[..] I open it on the upper package

As already mentioned in the comments by Holger, although the naming of packages in Java is (or, seems to be) hierarchical, packages are not; each package name defines its own independent namespace.
In other words, opening the package fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop does not also open the package fr.plaglefleau.banksystemdesktop.api.models.bankapi.response.get. As far as Java is concerned they are two distinct and separate entities (i.e. the latter is not nested in the former).
